# Creating a directory on client machine using applet

Tags: java, file, security, applet, directory

I have a self signed applet running in the browser, this applet should create a directory on the client machine using this code.

```
boolean success = (new File("myDir")).mkdirs();
if (!success) {
     System.err.println("Directory creation failed");
}
```

However, when I run it in the browser (under Apache) and after accepting all the security warnings I can't find `myDir` directory on my machine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) I strongly recommend you prefix that path with `System.getProperty("user.home")` to know ***where*** to look for the directory.

Comment: So ..where is that SSCCE?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not looking at the right place...
Given your code snippet, this directory will be created in the current working directory. To be sure where that is on your machine just try to see what the following code gives out :

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving it an absolute path so it's creating myDir in the working directory that the browser runs it in, probably a temp dir, or even a "sandbox" area in some browsers.

Comment: what do you mean by absolute path like this path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\myDir"?
is there a more generic path?

Comment: You can use the system's environment variables to get specific paths. To get the user's home directory would be System.getProperty("user.home")

However even this may not solve your issue as Nguyen pointed out below, if your applet is in a sandbox it's not allowed access to the local filesystem.

Comment: How can i know if my applet is in sandbox?

Comment: Since you signed it it should be privileged. If you get a security exception you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem) to run privileged code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you run applet in sandbox, so You cannot access into user machine resource.
Please see document:
[Applet security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: but i signed my jar files isn't it means i'm not in sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I mean. Do you check your permission to create file?

Comment: I think that this is my problem I didn't grant any permissions.
I need to use policy tool right?

Comment: *"I need to use policy tool right?"*  Wrong.  If an applet is digitally signed, it already has as much access to the client machine as any policy file will give it.

Comment: You can not create a folder in system folder(ex: desktop), if your role is USER.

Comment: @Nguyen "You can not create a folder in system folder(ex: desktop), if your role is USER." can you elaborate? is there a solution to create a folder on user's machine?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've self signed my applet and yet it won't create a folder on user's machine.

Comment: You can create file in User working directory. The user directory is gotten from property "user.dir"